# could a password policy be dynamic, depending on password lenght

Tags: password, pam

I would like to set different password complexity depending for exemple on the password length.

Is it possible to make conditions, so I can have a high level of complexity with password length=8 and a low level or no complexity with password length=16 or more.

thanks for your tips, tricks and advices.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can set a password of any complexity for any length, but your question is probably about pam password restrictions. The following may seem like not answering your question, but it does as it probably renders your question irrelevant:

Your question suggests the idea that the security of a short password can be improved by requiring more complexity. Many people seem to think this way, but the opposite is true. Short passwords are mainly a problem where brute force attacks are possible (like access to password hashes is gained).

Say, you have an 8-character password composed of a collection of 26 uppercase, 26 lowercase, 10 digits and 18 other characters, this makes 80^8 = 1677E+12 combinations to test.

If there is a requirement to use each of the character classes at least once, most combinations do not need to be tested, because they are not allowed. The number is reduces this to 26*26*10*18*80^4*(number of permutations) combinations, which is only 5E+12 combinations times the number of permutations, which still is much, much less than without restrictions.

So if you allow short passwords, don't make it worse by restricting them!

Comment: I am not trying to improve security, as I already have brute force detection, I am trying to improve user management, with very special users. I would like them to use simple unrelated words x 4 as passwords, with no complexity. but no abandon complexity with shorter passwords.